# How to split the values stored in List<Series>

Tags: java, split, influxdb

I need help in splitting the values stored in list

Please find the below code:

```
public class Connect_InfluxDB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Connect to InfluxDB
        InfluxDB influxDB = InfluxDBFactory.connect("http://localhost:8086");

        // Create a database
        String dbName = "jmeter";

        System.out.println("SELECT sum"+"("+"errorCount"+")"+"/"+"count"+"("+"responseTime"+")"+" FROM "+ "requestsRaw");
        Query errorcount = new Query("SELECT sum"+"("+"errorCount"+")"+"/"+"count"+"("+"responseTime"+")"+" FROM "+ "requestsRaw", dbName);

        QueryResult queryResult = influxDB.query(errorcount);

        // iterate the results and print details
        for (QueryResult.Result result : queryResult.getResults()) {

            // print details of the entire result
            System.out.println(result.toString());

            // iterate the series within the result
            for (QueryResult.Series series : result.getSeries()) {
                System.out.println("series.getName() = " + series.getName());
                System.out.println("series.getColumns() = " + series.getColumns());
                System.out.println("series.getValues() = " + series.getValues());
                System.out.println("series.getTags() = " + series.getTags());
            }
        }

        Query passcount = new Query("SELECT 1 - sum"+"("+"errorCount"+")"+"/"+"count"+"("+"responseTime"+")"+" FROM "+ "requestsRaw", dbName);

        QueryResult queryResult1 = influxDB.query(passcount);

        // iterate the results and print details
        for (Result result : queryResult1.getResults()) {

            // print details of the entire result
            System.out.println(result.toString());

            // iterate the series within the result
            for (Series series : result.getSeries()) {
                System.out.println("series.getName() = " + series.getName());
                System.out.println("series.getColumns() = " + series.getColumns());
                System.out.println("series.getValues() = " + series.getValues());
                System.out.println("series.getTags() = " + series.getTags());
            }
        }

        // Delete the database
        //influxDB.deleteDatabase(dbName);
    }

    public List<Series> getSeries() {
        return this.getSeries();
      }
}
```

i'm getting the below result for the above pass and error count query

```
Error count-series.getValues() = [[1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, 0.7083333333333334]]

Passcount-series.getValues() = [[1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, 0.29166666666666663]]
```

i would like to take only the values from the list (Ex:0.708 & 0.291) how would i do that.Please throw some light. Any advise on this would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: question is not clear. Are you expecting to get only the second value ? like `[[0.7083333333333334]]` ? How this value is generated ? Is not it from your query ?

Comment: As a side note, why do you try to obfuscate your sql queries? I mean `"SELECT sum"+"("+"errorCount"+")"+"/"+` ???

Comment: This seems to be a InfluxDB special question. Did you debug the series object and check the data type of series.getValues()?